Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' in flutter app
I am trying to deploy a flutter app to firebase host but I have an error in my index.js file that I don't know how to fix.
I have done the flutter build web command, firebase init command, and then firebase deploy.
I am running into a problem when the process tries to deploy the function I have in the index.js file.
index.js:
import { firestore } from "firebase-functions"; <<< ERROR HERE
import { initializeApp, messaging } from "firebase-admin";
initializeApp();

export const updateTrxnNotification = firestore
    .document("company/{companyId}/trxns/{trxnsId}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      const documentId = context.params.documentId;

      // // Access other fields as needed from newValue

      // // Constructing the notification payload
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Document Updated",
          body: "Document ${documentId} has been updated.",
        },
        // You can add additional data fields as needed
        data: {
          documentId: documentId,
        },
      };

      // // Get the device token from your Firestore document
      const deviceToken = newValue.deviceToken;

      // Send the notification
      return messaging().send(deviceToken, payload);
    });

I get the error on the first import statement.
Here is the error:
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
And there isn't a quick fix available.
I have read a few of the questions asking about the same error but they are fairly old and their suggestions are not working for me.
Here is my eslintrc.js file:
/* eslint linebreak-style: ["error", "windows"]*/
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
module.exports = {
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    "no-restricted-globals": ["error", "name", "length"],
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
    "quotes": ["error", "double", {"allowTemplateLiterals": true}],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.spec.*"],
      env: {
        mocha: true,
      },
      rules: {},
    },
  ],
  globals: {},
};

I have tried adding "sourceType": module to the parserOptions line but it didn't work either.
How can I fix this so I can either get this to deploy to firebase host or move to the next error?
Thanks

Ensure you have doublequotes (" ") when adding the sourceType and its value to your eslintrc.js file.
module.exports = {
  ...
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
  ...
};

